# Discover access read create LOCAL files on computer using Html Javascript PHP ? Local purpose, NOT for web online server

Tags: javascript, html, file, local

My questions is :
there is a way to discover/access/read/create LOCAL files on computer using Html Javascript ? 
For LOCAL purpose only, NOT for web online server

I understand for security/privacy all HTML language CANNOT access to local files.
(except cookies files...)

I develop a couple of very simple application for myself, to use on LOCAL computer, STANDALONE, PORTABLE,
I use HTML JavaScript because I already know them, I cost me too much time to install or learn a new coding system, HTML are very flexible for me.

Mostly now is for **discover files in a folder**, accces to them and read them.

exemple :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
    {
    font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif ;  
    background-color:#222 ; 
    color:#eee ; 
    margin:0px ; 
    padding:0px ; 
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<button type="button" style="position:fixed; right:0px; top:  0px ; "     onclick="window.location.reload()">Reload Full Page (F5)</button>

<div id="OUTPUT_1">OUTPUT_1</div>

<script>
/* file list */ 
var LIST = "" ; 
LIST = "\
rain1.ogg$\
rain2.ogg$\
thunder1.ogg$\
thunder2.ogg$\
" ; 
var file = []; 
file = LIST.split("$"); 
file.pop();


/* filter by type or extension */
//var type = ogg ; (not used, for now)


/* make table */
var MEGA_OUT = "" ; 

MEGA_OUT += "Numbers of Sound : "+file.length ;

MEGA_OUT += "<table>" ; 
for ( var i=0  ;  i<file.length  ;  i++ ) 
    {
    //start table line
    MEGA_OUT += "<tr>" ; 
    //name cell
    MEGA_OUT += "<td class='file_name'>" ; 
    MEGA_OUT += file[i] ; 
    MEGA_OUT += "</td>" ; 
    //player        
    MEGA_OUT += "<td class='file_name'>" ; 
    MEGA_OUT += "<audio controls>" ;
    MEGA_OUT += "<source src='"+file[i]+"' type='audio/ogg'>" ;
    MEGA_OUT += "Your browser does not support the audio element." ;
    MEGA_OUT += "</audio>" ;
    MEGA_OUT += "</td'>" ; 
    //end line
    MEGA_OUT += "</tr>" ; 
    }
MEGA_OUT += "</table>" ; 
document.getElementById("OUTPUT_1").innerHTML = MEGA_OUT ; 

</script>

<!-- END  -->
</body>
</html>
```

In this exemple, will be great if I can just copy my files in the folder, and reload my HTML to preview them.
But it's not only for few audio files, it's for many. It can help me also for pictures, video shots, text notes, etc...

Thank you so much !

Comment: If you know that this cannot be done, why are you asking how to do it? I would invest an hour or two looking into python, php or a language that will be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use PHP server for that. If You are familiar with JavaScript, You can easily setup a `Node.js` server in a minute on a local machine and develop everything with much more available functions and power.

Checkout some tutorials. This will take less time to learn, but You will be much easy to implement and develop later!

https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/2504541-ultra-fast-applications-using-node-js/2504972-creating-your-first-app-with-node-js

or
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp